# comapring array if the user type in then adding in list

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program where a user give 10 names and i the program have to check if the user gave same names and then program add that to a list and show them. My problem is i dont understand how to check same names.

```
string[] namen = new string[10];
string[] names = new string[10];
List<string> result = new List<string>();

string naam;

for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Geef {0} naam in: ", i+1);
    naam = Console.ReadLine();
            namen[i] = naam;
}

for(int i= 0;i<10;i++)
{
     namen[i] = names[i];
}
Array.Sort(names);
for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ )
{
    if (namen[i]==namen[i])
    {
        result.Add(names[i]);
    }
}
foreach(string show in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(show);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Do you want to check if a user enters a duplicate name?

Comment: yea  i wanna check it then want to add it to a list

Comment: Your question already has an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578260/how-to-find-all-duplicate-from-a-liststring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all duplicate from a List<string>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578260/how-to-find-all-duplicate-from-a-liststring)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `List<string>` and check if the name is allready contained:

```
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    List<string> allreadyEntered = new List<string>();

    string naam;

    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Geef {0} naam in: ", i+1);
        naam = Console.ReadLine();

        if(names.Contains(naam) && !allreadyEntered.Contains(naam))
        {
             allreadyEntered.Add(naam);
        }

        names.Add(naam);
    }

    foreach(string naam in allreadyEntered)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(naam);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I've eddited my answer to eliminate that problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using `System.Linq`

```
string[] names = namen.GroupBy(n => n).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();
```

`GroupBy(n => n)` groups the string array according to their values.

`Where(g => g.Count() > 1)` eliminates the groups with single instances.

`Select(g => g.Key)` selects the string value of each group.

`ToArray()` gives the result as an array

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this instead:

```
string[] namen = new string[10];

    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Geef {0} naam in: ", i+1);
        namen[i] = Console.ReadLine();;
    }
    namen
       .GroupBy (n =>n)
       .Where (w =>w.Count () > 1)
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(f=>Console.WriteLine(f.Key));
    Console.ReadLine();
```